# SAS/PROC SQL: Remove initial zeros from an alphanumeric field

Tags: sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I need to remove some initial zeros from a field (it appears as an alphanumeric one in the DB) like this:

```
cod_acometida
000000000003391901
000000000008271401
000000000007696901
000000000005504701
000000000002298401
000000000000332701
000000000013942801
```

It's a variable number of characters but they are always zeros at the beginning of the string. I'm new at SAS, not sure if RegEx is applicable.

I'm using Enterprise Guide 7.15.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data have;
input cod_acometida :$20.;
datalines;
000000000003391901
000000000008271401
000000000007696901
000000000005504701
000000000002298401
000000000000332701
000000000013942801
;

data want;
   set have;
   cod_acometida = substr(cod_acometida, verify(cod_acometida, '0'));
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
data have;
input cod_acometida :$18.;
cards;
000000000003391901
000000000008271401
000000000007696901
000000000005504701
000000000002298401
000000000000332701
000000000013942801
;

data want;
set have;
cod_acometida = put(cod_acometida*1, best18.);
run;
```